# Pandas dataframe: assigning a certain value to columns/rows matching a Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am new to Python, so forgive me if the answer is easy. Let's assume the following Dataframe:

```
columns_info = pd.DataFrame(index=infos,columns=df2.columns)
```

Where info is:

```
dict_keys(['Reference_COS_ID', 'Station_Description', 'Reference_Axis_ID', 'Station_ID', 'Cut', 'Coordinates'])
```

And df2.columns is:

```
Index(['Condition', 'Case', 'Flight Point', 'Mass case', 'DB Code',
       'Minmax/Nz', 'Mass,Kg', 'Mach #', 'VTAS', 'QDYN',
       ...
       'VT.0060.26', 'VT.0070.26', 'VT.0080.26', 'VT.0090.26', 'VT.0100.26',
       'VT.0110.26', 'Unnamed: 499', 'DB Code.1', 'Mass,Kg.1', 'Mach #.1'],
      dtype='object', length=503)
```

How can I assign a value to all the columns that match a regex?
I would like to to something like this:

```
columns_info['VT\.....\.26']['Station_ID']=0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex that matches for digits between "VT." and ".26:

```
df.loc['Station_ID', df.columns.str.contains("VT\.(\\d+)\.26") ] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.filter` with regex to get the columns which start with `VT` and end with `26`:

```
# Filter only columns which start with VT and end with 26
df1 = columns_info.filter(regex='^VT.*26$')
# Assign 0 to index Station_ID
df1.loc['Station_ID'] = 0

# Get dataframe without the columns in df1
df2 = columns_info.drop(df1.columns, axis=1)

# Concat both dataframes to final dataframe
columns_info = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
print(columns_info)
                    VT.0060.26 VT.0070.26 VT.0080.26 VT.0090.26 VT.0100.26  \
Reference_COS_ID           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
Station_Description        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
Reference_Axis_ID          NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
Station_ID                   0          0          0          0          0   
Cut                        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
Coordinates                NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

                    VT.0110.26 Condition Case Flight Point Mass case DB Code  \
Reference_COS_ID           NaN       NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN     NaN   
Station_Description        NaN       NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN     NaN   
Reference_Axis_ID          NaN       NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN     NaN   
Station_ID                   0       NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN     NaN   
Cut                        NaN       NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN     NaN   
Coordinates                NaN       NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN     NaN   

                    Minmax/Nz Mass,Kg Mach # VTAS QDYN Unnamed: 499 DB Code.1  \
Reference_COS_ID          NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN   
Station_Description       NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN   
Reference_Axis_ID         NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN   
Station_ID                NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN   
Cut                       NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN   
Coordinates               NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN       NaN   

                    Mass,Kg.1 Mach #.1  
Reference_COS_ID          NaN      NaN  
Station_Description       NaN      NaN  
Reference_Axis_ID         NaN      NaN  
Station_ID                NaN      NaN  
Cut                       NaN      NaN  
Coordinates               NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the one before from Asmus suits better to what I needed to do, but your can be helpful in other frames!